# wcf data services - expose properties of the same type in data model

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm new to WCF data services. I have a quite simple data model. Some of its properties have the same type, like this:

```
public IQueryable<IntegerSum> HouseholdGoodsSums
{
    get
    {
        return GetData<IntegerSum>(DefaultProgramID, "rHouseholdGoodsPrice", IntegerSumConverter);
    }
}

public IQueryable<IntegerSum> StructureSums
{
    get
    {
        return GetData<IntegerSum>(DefaultProgramID, "rStructurePrice", IntegerSumConverter);
    }
}
```

The IntegerSum is a very very simple class:

```
[DataServiceKey("Amount")]
public class IntegerSum
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I navigate to my service in a web browser, I see the following error message:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Property 'HouseholdGoodsSums' and 'StructureSums' are IQueryable of types 'IntegrationServices.PropertyIntegrationServices.IntegerSum' and 'IntegrationServices.PropertyIntegrationServices.IntegerSum' and type 'IntegrationServices.PropertyIntegrationServices.IntegerSum' is an ancestor for type 'IntegrationServices.PropertyIntegrationServices.IntegerSum'. Please make sure that there is only one IQueryable property for each type hierarchy.'.

When I get rid of one of these two properties, the service starts working.

I searched for this error message in google, but haven't found a solution.
Is it really not allowed to have two properties with the same type in a data model? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comrade,

To address the error first, you're running into a limitation in the [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx) provider. Specifically, the Reflection provider doesn't support [MEST](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2008/05/16/mest-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work.aspx).

That said, there are better approaches to achieve what you're trying to achieve. You should probably not make IntegerSum an entity type (an entity type is a uniquely identifiable entity, which doesn't really fit your scenario). While you can't expose that directly, you can expose it as a [service operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx). That seems much closer to what you're trying to achieve.

A couple of ways to distinguish between whether or not something should be an entity:

1. If it has a key already, such as a PK in a database, it should probably be an entity type
2. If you need to create/update/delete the object independently, it must be an entity type

HTH,
Mark

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand I did it wrong way. All I've gotta do now is to expose two service operations (marked with WebGetAttribute) that return collections of integers.